# Best practice for defining superclass instance fields based on the subclass

Tags: java, superclass

I have an abstract super class and several subclasses that inherit fields defined in the super class, but each subclass has different values for those fields. When the subclass is called, I use the constructor to set the fields appropriately.

Should I use direct references to do this `field = value`, or should I use the super class set methods `setField(value);`?

I'd rather keep the fields private, so I want to avoid direct references.

The other alternative is to call the super constructor, which would allow me to use direct references in the super class constructor `super (T value)` and in the super class `SuperClass(T value){ field = value}`. Would this be the best way? I could even use set methods inside the super constructor, but this seems like it would be redundant.

Comment: You should probably re-evaluate your class hierarchy and see if is necessary.  It's possible that inheritance is creating more problems for you than it is solving.  Subclasses should not have a lot of the same fields with different values from a super class.  If you can't use any of the field values in the super abstract class, why are you defining them there in the first place?

Comment: Because they are common to all subclasses. Why declare them more than once? I am not declaring them in subclass.

Comment: Why not just define the fields in the abstract super class then but don't actually set them to any particular value?  You should be able to set up your abstract super class in a way that if a subclass does not set a value for any field, an exception is thrown.

Comment: That is what I am doing. I never said I was initializing the fields except through the subclass. Problem is, since they are private fields they must be accessed through the super constructor, or else by calling public super methods. I was just wondering which way is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One great advantage and one great reason why abstract superclasses are used is to save coding time and make your class architecture that much easier.
Therefore, if you have a superclass that has common fields with subclasses, then you should take a second look at your architecture.

To solve your problem, remove any redundant fields that are in the subclasses but already exist in the superclass. Whenever you want to utilize the fiels, simply use the superclasses reference. Call for instance the superclasses constructor to set the values for the fields etc.

Whenever you want to retrieve the fields, call "super.getValue(...)" etc

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should make them private and access them using getters and setters.  If subclasses are allowed to set them directly, they could violate the contracts of the superclass by setting invalid values.

And if the subclasses differ *only* in the values of those superclass fields, then you shouldn't use subclasses at all; just create instances of the superclass with different values.

Comment: If the fields have particular constraints you want to enforce via the abstract super class, I can see your point in creating accessors and mutators.  If that is not the case though, it would seem that zephos2014 might be better off just using protected fields and accessing them directly as he has not given a reason why he prefers private access.

Comment: Honestly, I was just following "best practices". If protected access keeps unrelated classes from changing the values, that might work fine.

Comment: If the fields don't have particular constraints, then the superclass is just acting as a dumb container for data that the subclass is responsible for.  That calls for composition, not inheritance.  Class hierarchies should be designed around common interfaces, not common data.